# tuple formatting and putting it it a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have two of the tuples like this :

```
('This is example string 1', "{'entities': [(96, 115, 'type_2')]}")
('This is example string 2', "{'entities': [(38, 42, 'type_1'), (5, 15, 'Modality'), (103, 128, 'File Name'), (58, 92, 'subtype_3')]}")
```

However, I want the double quotes ("") to be removed from both like this :

```
('This is example string 1', {'entities': [(96, 115, 'type_2')]})
('This is example string 2', {'entities': [(38, 42, 'type_1'), (5, 15, 'Modality'), (103, 128, 'File Name'), (58, 92, 'subtype_3')]})
```

Once it is done, the tuples should be appended to the list :

```
[('This is example string 1', {'entities': [(96, 115, 'type_2')]})
('This is example string 2', {'entities': [(38, 42, 'type_1'), (5, 15, 'Modality'), (103, 128, 'File Name'), (58, 92, 'subtype_3')]})]
```

Comment: Your list shows the double quotes back in the tuples. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Hi Nick,
No I have edited it, I don't want double quotes, when I try to print it individually, it doesn't shows anything, as soon as I create a tuple with two strings, it starts picking up the double quotes.

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` e.g. if the tuples are in a list, use `import ast;
result = [(v, ast.literal_eval(d)) for v, d in tuples]`

Comment: tuples are not in a list currently, they are appended later on.def creating_tuple():
    # my_tuple = ()
    tup_list = []
    df = pd.read_excel("sheet.xlsx")
    for i in df.index:
        data_1 = df['data'][i].lstrip()
        data_2 = data_1.rstrip()
        my_tuple = (data_2, df['entity'][i])
        print(my_tuple)
        input()

Comment: `my_tuple = (data_2, ast.literal_eval(df['entity'][i]))` should work

Comment: You can apply like this `new_list = [ast.literal_eval(i) if '{' in i  else i for i in tuple1 ]`